# Closedness of the set $V_1 a(\lambda) \Phi$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $G=\text{SL}(3,\mathbb R)$ and $\Gamma=\text{SL}(3,\mathbb Z)$. Let $a(\lambda)$ be the diagonal matrix $a(\lambda):=\text{diag}(\lambda,1,\lambda^{-1}),$ where $\lambda>0$.

Take $x\in G/\Gamma$ and consider $\Phi:=\{g\in G:gx=x\}$, where the action is just the usual left action on the coset space.

Let $V_1=\{v_1(t):t\in \mathbb R\}$, where $v_1(t)$ is the matrix

$$v_1(t):=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & t & t^2/2 \\
0 & 1 & t \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

I wonder if the product set $V_1 a(\lambda) \Phi$ is a closed subset of $G$. (Maybe the fixed element $a(\lambda)$ is irrelevant here, but I am [not very sure about that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3680776/closedness-of-the-subset-acb-when-ab-is-closed-in-a-topological-group). )

Comment: The answer depends on $\lambda$ and on $x$: Sometimes it is closed and sometimes not Generically, it is dense in $G$. The issue is closely related to Ratner's theorem, which classifies closures of such subsets.